# Flat arc to 3D curve

Tags: transforms

[image]
I have a task to create a 3D model from a paper-based plan, part of which illustrates a curve to be cut from aluminium and then bent into an arc for use vertically  – easy in life, perplexing (so far) in Blender.
It's almost like I need to take each vertex on the outer edge and rotate it around the corresponding local X axis of the corresponding inner vertex.

Can anybody suggest a way to take a 'C' shape, as shown above, and turn it 'edge on', please?
I've spent an inquisitive morning tinkering, but it's time to ask for a hand now.

Comment: so you are supposed to go from the illustrated flat shape to a bent one? Also, do you mean that it's supposed to be animated? Have you tried the Simple Deform modifier?

Comment: Do you need it to be modelled as a mesh or as a curve? Will there be two objects (C Shape & Arc) with the same 'length'? Or one is the shape key of the other?

Comment: @moonboots the flat shape was cut from aluminium and then the ends pulled together, making a curved 'belt' to hold some kind of tapering pipework, hence the need for the initial curved cut, rather than a plain rectangle.

I don't need it animated, although it might be some welcome relief for the end of the project to stick a build modifier on!

Simple Deform modifier does nothing like yours, as shown below, when I load it into a test rig. I also have XYZ options on mine not shown on your example – a Blender 2.79/2.80 difference?

Comment: @BlenderDadaist There's one shape, only. It's cut out, on the original plan, as a shallow 'C' shape and then simply wrapped around a tapered pipe (hence the odd curve rather than a long strip).
Above is shown the Before and After concept – sizes not to be taken literally, the image is is for illustration only.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, what you could do is:

- Use your picture as a background image.
- Create a cylinder, extrude inwards.
- Only keep an arc.
- Scale on the X axis (because it seems a bit deformed).
- Make sure you've applied the rotation with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>.
- Give it a *Simple Deform* modifier / *Bend* mode. Give it the *Angle* value you want.

[image]

Comment: I don't have this layout or behaviour for Simple Deform/Bend. Is there a 2.79/2.80 difference?

Comment: in 2.8 I think you can determine the bending axis, while in 2.7 it will be Z unless you choose an axis object. Is what I've done close to what you want? Please describe your problem

Comment: As stated in the comments above from 20191014, the Simple Deform bend option has XYZ axis options under 2.80 but, unfortunately, a test duplicating your otherwise excellent suggestion with the Z axis (or any other, for that matter) specified produced inferior results, markedly different to those you show.

Comment: Is what I've done the thing you want? In what way doesn't it work when you try it? For example have you applied the rotation of your object?